# LoadLibraryEx returns 0 in c# when the code was deployed on IIS 6.0 in windows server 2003 box

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7, iis-6

I am getting the return value of `LoadLibraryEx` as "0" after my webservice code has been deployed on IIS 6.0 which is on windows server 2003 box. I have the original code in windows xp(local) which is working fine and is not 
returning 0 for this `LoadLibraryEx`. I am totally confused and not sure why it is returning zero now when it is deployed on IIS 6.0.

IntPtr handle = LoadLibraryEx(dllFullPath, IntPtr.Zero, 0x00000008);

getting a return value of 14001 when i used the Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()

Comment: What is your code? Share your code so people can help you.

Comment: GetLastError() value after LoadLibraryEx returning 0 would be useful too.

Comment: Usually when LoadLibraryEx returns 0 or null it is because some dependency of the library is not available. Make sure that all of the dependencies are either in the directory with the dll or are available in the paths that Windows automatically searches.

Comment: i made sure that all the dependency's are available, but i am still getting the same error 14001 and with return value 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is [`ERROR_SXS_CANT_GEN_ACTCTX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681384.aspx#ERROR_SXS_CANT_GEN_ACTCTX).

> The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.

Using sxstrace.exe might be a little tricky in your scenario. It's certainly worth checking the event logs to see if they contain clues.

My guess would be that the problem box is missing the appropriate MSVC runtime. Make sure that you deploy the MSVC runtime that is used by the DLL you are trying to load. That's the obvious first thing to try before attempting to debug the problem.

Comment: this is the error that i am seeing in my windows server 2003 event logs.
"Resolve Partial Assembly failed for Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT. Reference error message: The referenced assembly is not installed on your system." but i am not sure what i am suppose to do as i am new to visual studio. Please suggest

Comment: my local machine where dll that i am referring to generated is an windows xp and visual studio 2008 professional edition -ENU is installed.

Comment: OK, that means that the DLL is linked against the debug runtime. Which cannot be redistibuted. The right solution is to get a version of the DLL that links to the release build of the runtime. If you are compiling the DLL you can do that. If not you'll need to contact whoever supplied the DLL.

Comment: OK, comments crossed. It looks like you are building the DLL. So, make sure you build it targeting the release CRT. And then install the VS2008 redistributable package on each machine which needs to use the DLL.

Comment: do i still need to install vs2008 redistributable package on windows server 2003 even though i just use the release dll?

Comment: Yes, the redist has to be on any machine that uses the DLL. Of course, it may already be there. But redist doesn't put on debug CRT because that's not redistributable.